# JQuery UI dialog position titlebar outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to eliminate users having to scroll to the top of a long dialog box in order to close out. The close button is positioned on the title bar.

Not sure if positioning the title bar directly on top of the dialog is an option, but would prefer to keep the original structure. Any ideas? Thanks.

Exiting on a click event is useful for other circumstance, but not here. The problem is rudimentary.

For whatever reason, the dialog scroll comes up besides the title bar, very unusual. Not able to post an image yet (< 10 reputation points).

Comment: A fiddle would be nice. Another option would be javascript that on a click of the dialog, anywhere, it closes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qb7YS/)

JS

```
var openthedialog = $( ".textfordialog" ).dialog({
                             autoOpen: false,
                             height: 'auto',
                             width: 200,
                             position: {my: "top left",
                                        at: "right bottom",
                                        of: "#clickme"}
                                                   });

$('#clickme').click(function(){
           openthedialog.dialog('open');
});
$('.textfordialog p').on('click', function(){
           openthedialog.dialog('close');
});
```